# Does Nativescript use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, nativescript

We have developed an app using Nativescript and when the app was uploaded to APP Store i got a mail from Apple stating "Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs". I am using OAuth plugin for authentication which open a browser control for login, I just want to clarify if any of the Nativescript components use webview.

I read through the Apple document which states any component using the following deceleration would not be accepted in the future

class UIWebView : UIView

but instead should be replaced with WKWebView, could some one shed some light?

Does any of the default Nativescript components or the OAuth2 plugin use this API?

Comment: That depends on which version of NativeScript you are using, as far I recall UIWeView was replaced by WKWebView in v3.4.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, we are currently using Nativescript version ^4, going by what you said we do not have any issue with UIWeView.

Comment: That's correct. Make sure none of your plugins are using UIWebView, the latest versions use WKWebView but older versions of OAuth2 used UIWebView.

Comment: We have updated the OAuth2 plugin to latest and tried but still get the same message from Apple, **ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs nativescript**. Is there was way I can identify which component is using the API...?

Comment: You may simply search for the API references, that should do mostly. Try removing plugins one by one and see if error is still reproduced.